# C# Set Property Value With Reflection

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create a method that dynamically sets properties of a `PaymentMethod` using reflection. However, the issue is that the class property is neither being set nor throwing any exceptions.

```
private static AsyncLocal<PaymentMethodDto> asyncLocalEntityDto = new();

public static PaymentMethodDto EntityDto
{
    get => asyncLocalEntityDto.Value;
    set => asyncLocalEntityDto.Value = value;
}

 public static void SetEntityProperty(string propertyName, object propertyValue)
 {
     PropertyInfo property = typeof(PaymentMethodDto).GetProperty(propertyName);

     if (property != null && property.CanWrite)
     {
         property.SetValue(asyncLocalEntityDto, propertyValue);
     }
     else
     {
         throw new ArgumentException($"Property '{propertyName}' not found or is read-only in PaymentMethod");
     }
 }

 [Fact]
 public void SetEntityProperty_SetIdProperty_ShouldSetIdCorrectly()
 {
     // Arrange
     var dto = new PaymentMethodDto();

     // Act
     PaymentMethodHelper.SetEntityProperty(nameof(PaymentMethodDto.Id), 100);

     // Assert
     Assert.Equal(100, dto.Id);
 }

 [Fact]
 public void SetEntityProperty_SetPersonIdProperty_ShouldSetPersonIdCorrectly()
 {
     // Arrange
     var dto = new PaymentMethodDto();

     // Act
     PaymentMethodHelper.SetEntityProperty(nameof(PaymentMethodDto.PersonId), 200);

     // Assert
     Assert.Equal(200, dto.PersonId);
 }

public record struct PaymentMethodDto(int? Id, int PersonId, BenefitTypeEnum BenefitTypeId, string User, DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate);
```

I had tried also with `property.SetValue(asyncLocalEntityDto.Value, propertyValue);` but with the same result.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] including how the function is called?

Comment: How do you expect `SetEntityProperty` to access the `PaymentMethod` that you've created and kept a reference of just in a local variable?

Comment: (Your `SetEntityProperty` method uses `asyncLocalEntityDto`, which is entirely separate from the instance created with `var dto = new PaymentMethod();`.)

Comment: Ok but and asyncLocalEntityDto are not changed

Comment: @vladev_ops I reworded your question to improve readability. Please review to ensure it still expresses what you originally meant.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't be using `AsyncLocal<T>` _at all_....

Answer (score 1):

First-off: your xUnit tests, as-written, don't work: your tests set-up a `dto` local, but they don't pass that `dto` to `SetEntityProperty` - you seem to be expecting `AsyncLocal` to be doing some magic, when in reality the `EntityDto.Value` holds *another* separate `default()` value of `PaymentMethodDto`.

So rip that code out and pass `PaymentMethodDto` in a new parameter to `SetEntityProperty`.

> I want to create a method that dynamically sets properties of a `PaymentMethod` using reflection. However, the issue is that the class property is neither being set nor throwing any exceptions.

Your code has this:

```
public record struct PaymentMethodDto(int? Id, int PersonId, BenefitTypeEnum BenefitTypeId, string User, DateTime? StartDate, DateTime? EndDate);
```

...which is a **struct**, a *value-type*, which is not a `class`.

While `record struct` types *do* have `{ get; set; }` properties, invoking a property setter on value-type using reflection is basically a glorified NOOP because the reflection API [will box a new copy of the value-type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) when it passes it into `PropertyInfo.SetValue`, so the written changes gets lost when the `SetValue` call returns.

To make it work, you need to change `PaymentMethodDto` to be a `record class` type instead of `record struct` - but if you do this then those properties become `init` properties - which still doesn't work...

...as since .NET Core 3.x, `readonly` fields (which are the backing-store for `init`-properties in `record class` types) cannot be mutated via reflection *at all* - note that using `FieldInfo.SetValue` on an *instance* `readonly` fields *fails silently*, [while using `FieldInfo.SetValue` on a `static readonly` field will throw a `FieldAccessException` (yes, this is an annoying inconsistency)](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/11571)

So your code never would have worked:

- your `dto` struct wasn't being passed into `SetEntityProperty`.
- `AsyncLocal` does not perform magic teleportation.
- value-types lose any changes when passed as a boxed reference into `PropertyInfo.SetValue` or `FieldInfo.SetValue`.
- and a a `record class` type, the fields cannot be modified using reflection but fail silently.

Comment: AsyncLocal resolve the issue, thanks